# Why does both my IF- and ELSE-statement run?

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm trying to learn C# and because of that I wanted to create some simple applications in C#. When I first create the user and then create the pet, using the name I put in the owner object, I can see it loop through the IF statement while debugging, then after looping through the IF statement, it also loops through the else statement? Without debugging, it also returns both the if and else statement.

**My main method**

```
namespace Pet_Clinic
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Owner newOwner = new Owner();
            Pet pet = new Pet();

            bool running = true;

            while (running)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Pet Clinic Menu");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("1. Create customer");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Add pet to customer");
                Console.WriteLine("3. Get pets from customer.");
                Console.WriteLine("5. Quit");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.Write("Pick an option: ");

                int choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.Write("Enter name of owner: ");
                        string belongsTo = Console.ReadLine();

                        Console.Write("Enter adress: ");
                        string ownerAddress = Console.ReadLine();

                        Console.Write("Enter email: ");
                        string ownerEmail = Console.ReadLine();

                        Console.Write("Enter phonenumber: ");
                        string ownerPhonenumber = Console.ReadLine();

                        newOwner.CreateOwner(belongsTo, ownerAddress, ownerEmail, ownerPhonenumber);

                        
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Owner created successfully.");
                        Console.Write("Press enter to return to menu: ");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter pet name:");
                        string petName = Console.ReadLine();

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter pet breed:");
                        string petBreed = Console.ReadLine();

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter pet age:");
                        int petAge = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter owner name:");
                        string ownerName = Console.ReadLine();

                        Owner owner = newOwner.FindOwnerByName(ownerName);
                        if (owner == null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"No owner with the name {ownerName} exists.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pet.CreatePet(petName, petBreed, petAge, owner);
                            Console.WriteLine($"Pet {petName} added to owner {ownerName} successfully.");
                        }
                        Console.Write("Press enter to return to menu: ");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        running = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid option.");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My owner class**

```
namespace Pet_Clinic.Model
{
    public class Owner
    {
        /* Fields */
        public string belongsTo { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        /* Methods */

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{belongsTo} - {Address} - {PhoneNumber} - {Email}";
        }

        public List<Owner> owners = new List<Owner>();
        

        public Owner()
        {
            // Initialize the owners list in the constructor
            owners = new List<Owner>();
        }
        // Method to create the owner object
        public void CreateOwner(string name, string address, string email, string phonenumber)
        {
            Owner newOwner = new Owner()
            {
                belongsTo = name,
                Address = address,
                Email = email,
                PhoneNumber = phonenumber,
            };
            owners.Add(newOwner);
        }
         // Method to find the owner taking one parameter.
        public Owner FindOwnerByName(string ownerName)
        {
            // Loop through the owners list and return the first owner that matches the ownerName
            foreach (Owner owner in owners)
            {
                if (owner.belongsTo == ownerName)
                {
                    return owner;
                }
            }

            // If no matching owner is found, return null
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

**My pet class**

```
namespace Pet_Clinic.Model
{
    /* Fields */
    public class Pet
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Breed { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public Owner Owner { get; set; }

        public List<Pet> petList = new List<Pet>();

        /* Methods */


        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Name: {Name} Breed: {Breed} Age: {Age} Owner: {Owner}";
        }
        // Method to create pet
        public void CreatePet(string name, string breed, int age, Owner owner)
        {
            // Check if the owner exists in the owner list
            if (!owner.owners.Contains(owner))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Owner does not exist.");
                return;
            }

            Pet newPet = new Pet
            {
                Name = name,
                Breed = breed,
                Age = age,
                Owner = owner,
            };
            // Adds pet to list
            petList.Add(newPet);
        }
    }
}
```

Console application:
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to be a [mre]... that's more code than I'm willing to trawl through

Comment: There is only one `if .. else` in your code. And it will certainly not execute both branches in one iteration of your loop. It may of course, if you iterate your loop multiple times, choose a different branch every time depending on your inputs in that iteration ... And if you really see the outputs of both branches in one iteration, make sure, you have compiled and you are running the lastest version of your code (ie save -> compile -> run) ...

Comment: It would help to add your screen/console output. So we can see what you're seeing when your run it.

Comment: @Dizzy I've added the console output.

Comment: @freefaller I'm gonna read that now and see if I can make it easier.

Comment: What is the `public List<Owner> owners = new List<Owner>();` field meant to represent? It implies owners-have-owners, which is nonsensical in this case.

Comment: Read your output carefully. It doesn't come from the first `if()` branch, it comes from somewhere else. Each `Owner` instance has its _own_ owners list. If you create a `new Owner()`, it has an empty list. As @Dai explains, you probably want to store this owners list elsewhere.

Comment: @Dai I actually thought that I would have to create a list of owners AND pet in order to create the pet object if an owner exist in the list.

Comment: @CodeCaster Aight.. that makes sense.. I forgot that each time I create an object, I basically create another instance of the list, is that correct understood?

Comment: Yes, a `List<Owner>` is a list of Owner objects. However this doesn't mean that it automatically contains *all* Owners: each list-instance is independent and can contain other Owners

Comment: @xAndrula I think you have yet to understand the concept of _instance state_.

Comment: You don't want a `petList` inside of you `Pet` class, the same for `owners` and `Owner`. You just want one master list of Owners and one master list of Pets. A Pet can have one Owner (or none) and an Owner can have zero or more Pets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is it's ***not*** hitting both the if and else statements.

comparing this part of the output

[image: output]

with this code

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter owner name:");
string ownerName = Console.ReadLine();

Owner owner = newOwner.FindOwnerByName(ownerName);
if (owner == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"No owner with the name {ownerName} exists.");
}
else
{
    pet.CreatePet(petName, petBreed, petAge, owner);
    Console.WriteLine($"Pet {petName} added to owner {ownerName} successfully.");
}
```

- We see it ask for an owner name
- Call FindOwnerByName which it finds
- steps over the if statement and into the else statement
- We then call CreatePet which gives us the "Owner does not exist" message.

*this is because the owner is not present inside the list of owners of itself.  This is a different instance to the list of owners (newOwner) initialised inside of Main.*

- Finally we return from Create Pet and see the message "Pet mamba added..."